# SpringBoot+Stomp How to Monitor the Lifecycle？？

Tags: spring-boot

```java
@Controller
@EnableScheduling
public class WsController {

    @MessageMapping("/welcome")
    @SendTo("/topic/getResponse")
    public ResponseMessage say(RequestMessage message) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        return new ResponseMessage("Welcome, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }
}
```

I want to listen to endpoint's subscribe event and unsubscribe event on WebSocket like this:

```java
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/{user}")
@Slf4j
public class WebSocketUtil {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(){ log.info("open");}
      
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(){ log.info("close");}
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Spring should be firing websocket [subscribe](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionSubscribeEvent.html)/[unsubscribe](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionUnsubscribeEvent.html) events that you could listen on.

```java
@Component
public class MyListener {
  @EventListener(SessionSubscribeEvent.class)
  public void onSessionSubscribeEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Additional references:

- If you're unfamiliar with listening/publishing events in Spring, take a look at https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2.
- [Spring 4.3.x WebSocket reference - Events and Interception](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-appplication-context-events)